# How to add excel column to worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

Does any one know how to insert a new column to an already existing work sheet.

My current solution right now is to create a new excel file by copying all the columns from the existing excel then add the new col in the data table then exporting it to create a new excel. This method is somewhat tedious and just adding the new column to the already existing excel is the best way I see.

Here is my function for creating a new excel file

```
public static void ExportToExcel(DataTable tbl)
    {
        try
        {
            string dateNow = String.Format("{0:MM_dd_yyyy HH_mm_ss}", DateTime.Now);
            string excelFilePath = "C:\\The_Excel_File\\Result_" + dateNow;


            if (tbl == null || tbl.Columns.Count == 0)
                throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: Null or empty input table!\n");

            // load excel, and create a new workbook
            var excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            excelApp.Workbooks.Add();

            // single worksheet
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet workSheet = excelApp.ActiveSheet;

            // column headings
            for (var i = 0; i < tbl.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                workSheet.Cells[1, i + 1] = tbl.Columns[i].ColumnName;
            }

            // rows
            for (var i = 0; i < tbl.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                // to do: format datetime values before printing
                for (var j = 0; j < tbl.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    workSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = tbl.Rows[i][j];
                }
            }

            // check file path
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(excelFilePath))
            {
                try
                {
                    workSheet.SaveAs(excelFilePath);
                    excelApp.Quit();
                    //MessageBox.Show("Excel file saved!");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: Excel file could not be saved! Check filepath.\n"
                                        + ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            { // no file path is given
                excelApp.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: \n" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Open existing excel sheet and  get columncount and Rowcount using sheet used Range as stated below and covert this values to rangeaddress to write existing excel sheet

```
Sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

Sheet.UsedRagne.Rows.Count
```